# Should GWT ReuestFactory share the same EventBus with the application?

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

I have set up a RequestFactory in my GWT project. now the question is whether it is a good idea to share event bus between RequestFactory in the application?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the EventBus is made to be a central part of the application. You might be interested in knowing what's happening at the RequestFactory level and want to share events with that layer.

You can also centralize errors onFailure() by sending an event through the EventBus (for example to stop displaying the "waiting wheel" )

Anyway, it's not memory or performance consuming to share the EventBus, what consumes resources is when you subscribe and receive events you don't need (so be careful to type your GwtEvent#getType() correctly so you don't have a widely overused event type)